# Cvxpy portfolio optimization with constraint on the maximum number of assets

Tags: python, optimization, portfolio, cvxpy

I'm using `cvxpy` library to perform Portfolio Optimization.
However, instead of using the [Markowitz covariance model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4oVN.gif), I would like to introduce [new variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIo5R.gif) where `yi` variable is a binary variable that assumes value 1 if the asset i is included in the portfolio and 0 otherwise; `m` is the maximum number of assets I want to include in the portfolio; `r` is the return I want to get.

The Markowitz model, with constraint on the return is the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from cvxpy import *

# assets names
tickers = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF"]

# return matrix
ret = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1,6), columns = tickers)

# Variance_Coviariance matrix
covm = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6,6), columns = tickers, index = tickers)

# problem setting
x = Variable(len(tickers))              # xi variables
er = np.asarray(ret.T) * x              # expected return
min_ret = 0.2                           # minimum return
risk = quad_form(x, np.asmatrix(covm))  # risk
prob = Problem(Minimize(risk),          # problem setting function
[sum(x) == 1, er >= min_ret, x >= 0])
prob.solve()
```

The solution of this problem gives out a percentage to invest in each asset. But what if I want to invest on a limited number of asset `m`?
In order to do that I need to implement `yi` variables and make sure that their sum is equal to `m`
Hence, it should be something like this:

```
x = Variable(n)             
er = np.asarray(ret.T) * x 
risk = quad_form(x, np.asmatrix(covm))  
y = Variable(n, boolean=True)            #adding boolean variables
prob = Problem(Minimize(risk), [sum(x) == 1, er >= min_ret, x >= 0, sum(y) == k, sum(x) <= sum(y)])
prob.solve()
print(x.value)
print(y.value)
```

Unfortunately, this last chunk of code doesn't produce any result. Do you know why? Is there another method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In short, you have to link the variables x and y.

In case of long only constraints:
eps = 1e-5
[-1 + eps <= x - y, x - y <= 0]

This will set y to 1 if x > 0 and y to 0 if x == 0.

To make it work properly and not to be bothered by assets being just marginally above 0, you should also introduce a buy-in threshold.

[x - y >= buy_in_threshold - 1]

Note, that this problem is a mixed integer problem.
The ECOS BB solver can deal with that, if the problem remains small. Otherwise, you will need a commercial grade optimizer.